# Rectangle Area Calculation

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am trying to calculate the rectangle area in my application. I have created a simple layout but for some reason, data is not parsed into the application. I tried to print it in the console but nothing is shown.

**This is my Main Class:**

```
package com.example.week3labcode;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button calcButton;
    EditText number1, number2, resultFinal;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        calcButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext2);
        resultFinal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext3);
    }


    @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
        if(v == calcButton){
            number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext1);
            number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext2);
            double num1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());
            double num2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());
            calcRectangle(num1, num2);


        }
   }

    public void calcRectangle(double x, double y){

        double result = x * y;
        System.out.println(result);
        resultFinal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext3);
        resultFinal.setText(Double.toString(result));
        System.out.println('H' + result);

    }
}
```

**And the following code in my XML file that provides layout for the application:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rectangle Area Calculation" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Length" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtext1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter breadth" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtext2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Area in cm2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtext3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Entries" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set `OnClickListener` to your Button so `calcRectangle()` method is never called.

```
calcButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtext2);
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());
        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());
        calcRectangle(num1, num2);
    }
});
```

OR

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```